# Using a function to retrieve keys to put in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, api, streamlit

I am using streamlit and pandas.

I am using a function which returns keys from a API dictionary imported from another .py file. The function does return the keys I want. However when I convert the function into a DataFrame with streamlit I get errors. Can anyone help? I want to show the data represented by the function usdMarket() as a dataframe. The last line returns the data in json format.

```
import streamlit as st
import pandas as pd
from alt import bncQ

def usdMarket():
    for i in range (0, len(bncQ['symbols']), 1):
        if bncQ['symbols'][i]['quoteAsset']=='USD':
            bncQ['symbols'][i]

st.DataFrame(usdMarket())
```

Comment: Will you please show a sample of your dataframe?

Comment: I am using the api: https://api.binance.us/api/v3/exchangeInfo

The function returns the data which have the quoteAsset key 'USD'

Hope that makes sense

Comment: sample: 

{
"symbol":"BTCUSD"
"status":"TRADING"
"baseAsset":"BTC"
"baseAssetPrecision":8
"quoteAsset":"USD"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's unclear if you have to use those libraries, but this takes the url provided and parses it down to USD.

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
data = requests.get('https://api.binance.us/api/v3/exchangeInfo').json()
df = pd.DataFrame(data['symbols'])
dfUSD = df[['symbol', 'quoteAsset']].loc[df['quoteAsset']=='USD']
dfUSD

       symbol quoteAsset
0      BTCUSD        USD
1      ETHUSD        USD
2      XRPUSD        USD
3      BCHUSD        USD
4      LTCUSD        USD
..        ...        ...
127   CTSIUSD        USD
129    DOTUSD        USD
131    YFIUSD        USD
133  1INCHUSD        USD
135    FTMUSD        USD

[67 rows x 2 columns]
```

Comment: Thank you. This does work. Could you tell me what .loc does exactly?

Comment: Could you also tell me how you would return a string within a key? Say I want to use this api https://api.binance.com/api/v3/ticker/24hr

to return the keys which say 'USD' from symbol. How could I do this? I'm new to this and am still learning

Comment: I’ll let you read the docs on loc. but it’s a method to allow filtering. Others to review are iloc, at, and iat. All have different use cases.

Comment: As for your additional question, please open a new question and detail what your expected output should be. Also best if you give a shot and post come code you are trying.